# Android : Adb permission denied

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, adb

I am using ubuntu 13.04 I have just set up eclipse and android sdk. But whenever i try to run program or even if I am switching DDMS perspective it shows me permission denied error.
[image]

How to tackle this issue.

Comment: have you install ubuntu recently..?

Comment: yes i have installed it today only and got updated as well.

Comment: okay first install ia32-libs  using sudo apt-get install ia32-libs Command then tell me status ,is it solve or not

Answer (score 1):

@Manoj,

Try running following

- cd /home/manoj/....../platform-tools
- adb version

If you get a Permission denied error then

- chmod 770 adb
- adb version

you should get a response like "***Android Debug Bridge Version x.x.xx***"

If so the source of your problem was file permission and set the file permission appropriately

Also check if the $PATH includes the path to /home/manoj/....../platform-tools.

*Disclaimer*: I use Ubuntu 12.04 and adb at command prompt for my work. I hardly use eclipse for my current work.

Let us know your results

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Another issue might be adb's file permissions themselves, make sure the user you are using to run eclipse is the same as who owns the adb files. Also make sure that adb is actually executable. (These are both unlikely issues, but worth checking if the other solutions given don't fix it)

From the home directory, try 'adb' in terminal:

If 'adb' doesn't find the adb tool, then your path needs adjusted. (edit .bashrc with bash commands to append to the path the /tools directory of the android sdk, is probably the easiest way, then log out and back in to apply the settings)

If 'adb' says it needs root permission, then try 'sudo adb' and see if that works. (this shouldn't happen, but worth testing)

I'm not actually sure what it says for 'non executable' in 13.04, but it should be self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem through following steps:

```
1. copy & unzip eclipse to /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/
2. x86= sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
x64(Ubuntu 13.04 and earlier)= sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
x64(Ubuntu 13.10 and above)=   sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev:i386
I use ubuntu 14 and on this version listed packages have multiple dependencies, so if you could not install this package use apt-get -f install  (without package) . this statement install dependencies. 

3. sudo gedit /etc/environment
:/opt/android/android-sdk-linux/tools
:/opt/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

the same happened for me when i used `adb version` it showed adb server not installed ,and it showed how to fix it ,and now works fine ,install the adb server using the following code .

```
The program 'adb' is currently not installed. You can install it by    typing:

sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb
```